# Unable to show <div> if no data found in search input using MAP & FILTER

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple find search for users that if you input their **id**'s on the textfield, it will show there information inside the `div` tag.

I have no problem with getting the data of the user if you input number in the textfield that includes there id.

## PROBLEM

If the inputted number on the textfield is not match or not like with the user id's. It should be show the `div` containing *No Data Found.*, But unfortunately, It will not show in my current attempt.

Is something I missed here?

```js
let data = [
  {id:'120',name:'John Doe'},
  {id:'121',name:'William Wils'},
  {id:'122',name:'Brenda Grey'},
  {id:'123',name:'Joana Mill'},
  {id:'124',name:'Kert Dy'},
  {id:'125',name:'Danica Red'},
]
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key === "Enter"){
        this.search();
    }
});

function search(){
  let input = document.getElementById("search")
  if(input){
      container.innerHTML = data.filter(({id, name}) => id.includes(input.value)).map(
        ({ id, name }) =>
          !id ?
          `<div style="width:15rem;background-color:darkgray;color:white;box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;">
            <p style=padding:1.5rem;font-size:25px;">No Data Found.</p>
          </div>
          `
          :
          `<div style="width:15rem;background-color:lightblue;box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;">
            <p style=padding:1.5rem;">My ID: ${id}</p>
            <p style=padding:1.5rem;">My Name: ${name}</p>
          </div>
        `
      )
    .join("");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<label for="search">ID: </label>
<input type="number" id="search" autocomplete="off">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your mistake is that you check on 'id'. However at that point, you always have an id so it will always be true. The 'User not found' will never be triggered because you never get in that part of code as inputvalue doesn't include that id.